# htaccess rule for redirect on a page if requested url not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Dynamic url created is not the same as name of the page

Example:

The page name remains same example - example.php but the dynamic requested url is example-acd.php.

How to redirect to a new page if the dynamic url not found on the server.

Using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /404.php [L]
```

It is working fine for the static url but not for the dynamic url

Answer (score 1):

You need to use %{REQUEST_FILENAME} in place of %{REQUEST_URI}

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /404.php [L]
```

Comment: Not working because the FILEMAN is being created dynamically. I have tried the codes. URL is being created dynamically and there is no page of that name